# kivy AttributeError while trying to add score in game

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm making a game in kivy and I want to add a score, so every time I press on the soccer ball I want the score to increase by 1. I'm getting an error "self.root.ids.game_screen.ids.score.text = str(int(self.root.ids.game_screen.score.text) + 1) AttributeError: 'Ball' object has no attribute 'root' "
Below is my code!

main.py

```
    class Ball(Image):
    velocity = NumericProperty(0)


    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if Vector(self.center).distance(touch.pos) <= 33:
            self.root.ids.game_screen.ids.score.text = 
    str(int(self.root.ids.game_screen.ids.score.text) + 1)
        sound = SoundLoader.load('Soccer ball sound.wav')
        sound.play()
        self.source = "icons/ball.png"
        self.velocity = 275
    return super().on_touch_down(touch)


    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if Vector(self.center).distance(touch.pos) <= 33:
            self.source = "icons/ball.png"
    return super().on_touch_up(touch)


    class MainApp(App):
        GRAVITY = 300


    def move_ball(self, time_passed):
        ball = self.root.ids.game_screen.ids.ball
        ball.y = ball.y + ball.velocity * time_passed
        ball.velocity = ball.velocity - self.GRAVITY * time_passed


    def start_game(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.move_ball, 1/60.)




    




    MainApp().run()
```

gamescreen.kv

```
    Label:
        id: score
        size_hint: None, None
        font_size: dp(25)
        font_name: 'SackersGothicStd-Medium.otf'
        text: "0"
        color: "gold"
        pos_hint: { "center_x": 0.1, "center_y": 0.9}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @JohnAnderson I edited the code and make it shorter! What I'm trying to do is "on_touch_down" I want the score to increase by 1.

Answer (score 0):

The indentation of your code is messy, so I had to guess some stuff, please clean up your code for better answers.

Anyway, it seems like you are referring `root` from your python code inside your widget class. You can only reference `self.root` from your `App` sub-class. In order to reference special kv lang variables in python code like `root` & `app`, you have to do `self.get_root_window()` or `self.parent` or `App.get_running_app()` and `self` is `self` in both languages. If you are referring to the ids stored in a widget just simply do `self.ids`

Also, overriding `on_touch_down` is for special cases like not dispatching the touch event if it meets a certain condition. In order to get the button behavior you would like to achieve, do `from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior` and make your ball class inherit from it. This allows you to use the `on_press` and `on_release` events for your widget so you won't have to override `on_touch_down`.

Link to kivy behaviors docs: [kivy behaviors doc](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.behaviors.html)